# How I receive this ajax param in Cakephp?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, jquery-select2

I have a select2 plugin with ajax: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/

```
$("#UserCliente").select2({
placeholder: "Select a State",
 minimumInputLength: 3,
 ajax: { // instead of writing the function to execute the request we use Select2's convenient helper
url: "../clients/listaclients/",
dataType: 'json',
data: function (term) {
    return {
      select: term, // search term
    };
},
results: function (data) { // parse the results into the format expected by Select2.
    // since we are using custom formatting functions we do not need to alter remote JSON data
    return {results: data};
}
}
});
```

The ajax param sent:

[image]

I need to get the `select` value (ass). I'm trying this without sucess:

```
$this->request['select']
```

How can I receive this value?

Comment: Note that the URL should be `/clients/listaclients.json` when you expect JSON as return content. See [ajax-and-cakephp](http://www.dereuromark.de/2014/01/09/ajax-and-cakephp/). Also: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cake way: `$this->request->query['select']`

**EDIT:** The Cake 2.4+ way> `$this->request->query('select')`

Native PHP: `$_GET['select']`

Might be a good idea to get the [DebugKit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit) plugin. Helps you see all kinds of stuff, including request values and gives you an idea how to access them.

Comment: For Cake2.4 and above you can also use the wrapper method `$this->request->query('select')`.